# viewport meta tag: initial-scale property behaves differently when width <= 320

Tags: android, browser, webkit, viewport

I have been unable to understand how the `width` and `initial-scale` properties of `viewport` meta tag works

I have the following HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Viewport example A</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=321,initial-scale=1">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background: #800000;
}
p {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut eu massa
erat, eget bibendum tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Aenean lobortis,
leo et porttitor venenatis, sapien nunc sodales elit, ut condimentum
nibh lacus sed erat. Suspendisse potenti. Mauris facilisis, odio nec
commodo tempor, sem arcu dictum lacus, ac ultrices quam purus ultrices
nisl. Nullam cursus consequat nisl non sagittis. Cras convallis porta
dui eu viverra. Maecenas ultrices arcu sit amet nisi pharetra non
malesuada erat tempus.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I change the `width` and `initial-scale` properties and test the output with Samsung Galaxy SII phone with user-agent: `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-gb; GT-I9100G Build/GINGERBREAD) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1`.

The following three images have the following three properties respectively.

1. `width=321,initial-scale=2`
2. `width=321,initial-scale=1`
3. `width=321,initial-scale=0.5`

[image] .... [image] ....  [image]

The output above is what I expect. With `initial-scale=2`, the font as well as margins have been scaled twice that of `initial-scale=1` and 4 times that of `initial-scale=0.5`. I get similar expected output for any `width` > 320.

The following three images have the following three properties respectively.

1. `width=320,initial-scale=2`
2. `width=320,initial-scale=1`
3. `width=320,initial-scale=0.5`

[image] .... [image] .... [image]

The output here doesn't make sense to me.

1. The margin seen with `initial-scale=2` is same as that seen with `initial-scale=1`. Why?
2. With `initial-scale=0.5` we see that the margin is twice what we see with `initial-scale=1`. Why has the margin doubled instead of shrinking to half? Why hasn't the font changed here at all?

I get similar output that doesn't make sense to me for any `width` ≤ 320.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me either. The only thing I can think of is that the Samsung Android browser tries to do some "magic" to deal with iPhone-specific sites (that tend to use a hardcoded 320px width) and something simply goes wrong here.

Comment: could you post or comment results if you use 319?

Comment: @Sebas As I've mentioned in my post, the results are similar to that of width = 320. Output look similar to the second set of screenshots.

Comment: This article has some good info about how browsers might interpret web pages for devices with radically different 'resolutions' and other reasons https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Also you may check http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/metaviewport/ they did some tests with mobile browsers and things get really strange with default Android browser (not Chrome) on some devices.